# How do I get the Hosted Zone for a domain using Boto 3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-route53

In [Boto 2](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/route53.html#module-boto.route53.connection), I can get a Hosted Zone associated with a domain `domain` with

```
r53_2 = boto.route53.connection.Route53Connection()
hz = r53_2.get_zone(domain)
```

but in [Boto 3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/route53.html#id89), the [corresponding API](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/route53.html#Route53.Client.get_hosted_zone) requires an ID rather than a domain name

```
r53_3 = boto3.client('route53')
hz = r53_3.get_hosted_zone(id)
```

and I don't see any way to get the ID from the domain name, which is all I have access to.

How do I get the Hosted Zone for a domain using Boto 3?

Answer (score 6):

The **list_hosted_zones_by_name** is a bit misleading: it still returns a list, but the record which has the DNSName is listed first. CAUTION: if the record doesn't exist, it'll return the next record in some alphabetical order (I think), so grabbing the first on the list won't guarantee it's the one you want. Here's what worked for me:

```
import boto3, json

client = boto3.client('route53')
dnsName = 'example.com' 
response = client.list_hosted_zones_by_name(
    DNSName=dnsName, 
    MaxItems='1'
)
print(json.dumps(response, indent=4)) # inspect output
if ('HostedZones' in response.keys()
    and len(response['HostedZones']) > 0
    and response['HostedZones'][0]['Name'].startswith(dnsName)):
    hostedZoneId = response['HostedZones'][0]['Id'].split('/')[2] # response comes back with /hostedzone/{HostedZoneId}
    print('HostedZone {} found with Id {}'.format(dnsName, hostedZoneId))
else:
    print('HostedZone not found: {}'.format(dnsName))
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not in a position to test this right now, but can you use **.list_hosted_zones()**

You need to parse the result, but it is a start.

RL

Comment: Or better still  **.list_hosted_zones_by_name()**

Comment: Is that really the only way? Why switch to 3 then? 2 is much easier to use.

Comment: By all means stay with the old version of Boto in this case if it is serving your purposes.
AWS is always evolving and so are the means of interface.  We need to adapt with it to take advantage of the new features.  I know it sounds glib, but I have been in this industry for a 1/4 century, and the only thing that does not change is the constant change.  If you want to do something that does not change, become a brick layer.  An honorable and well paid frade with little change.

Comment: We'll my comment was fishing in that direction; but I was angling for some actual examples of why the evolution was useful (e.g., here why the indirection through IDs; why the discarding of the object model, etc.) rather than a sermon on change.

Comment: Fair enough.  Sorry about the sermon.  :-)
I have some references written during the Boto3 release.  If I find anything  in there I will make a point of posting it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this example will help...

```
    r53 = boto3.client('route53')
    zones = r53.list_hosted_zones_by_name(DNSName=domain)
    if not zones or len(zones['HostedZones']) == 0:
        raise Exception("Could not find DNS zone to update")
    zone_id = zones['HostedZones'][0]['Id']
```